# How to remove the least-recently-used image layers from Docker cache?

Tags: docker, storage, cache

I would like to (1) avoid running out of disk space due to Docker filling up its cache and (2) easily recover from such situation without discarding the cached objects that have been used recently. For this, it would be great if some command could remove all cached objects that haven't been **used** in a couple weeks or so. I'm aware of the following:

```
docker image prune -a --force --filter "until=240h"
```

But unless I'm mistaken, the above will delete any base image or layer that's older than 10 days (240 hours) even if we're still using it actively. Instead, we'd like to delete extra layers that were created during the development process and are no longer in use. Of course, we also want to delete downloaded base images that are no longer in use. We could then run such command every night and live happily ever after.

In short, how can we turn Docker's cache into an LRU cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Docuum](https://github.com/stepchowfun/docuum) will do LRU eviction of docker images. Docker itself doesn't store the date of last use, so Docuum monitors image usage and stores the necessary state itself.